# adding data to multidimensional array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I know that I should be using a list of arrays or instantiating a new class for each new row. I am currently trying to implement a jagged array however I cannot get it to work.
I am trying to search an existing jagged array (that works and is all good) for the account type "STUDENT" and put them into a new array and then add a new piece of information to each student. However when I do this I get a NullReferenceException and I do not know why this is occurring.
I am an A-Level computer science student and was told that I should avoid using pointers, yield statements and IENumerators which is why I have tried to avoid linked lists.

Code (csharp):

```
 public string[] users;
 public string[][] userArray;
 public string[] User = new string[3];
 private string userDataString;
 private int j;
 public string[][] StudentArray;

   public string[][] UserSorting(string[][] userArray)
{
    j = 0;
    //for each row in user array
    for (int i = 0; i <= userArray.Length; i++)
    {
        //Compares the stored account type to STUDENT
        if (userArray[i][5] == "STUDENT")
        {                
            //for each user value copy into the new array
            for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
            {

                StudentArray[j][x] = userArray[i][x];
                Debug.Log(StudentArray[j][x]);
            }
            //moves onto the next line ready for the next iteration 
            j++;
        }
    }

    return StudentArray;
}
```

}

Comment: First of all, `StudentArray[j][x]` would be a string, not an array, and `StudentArray[j]`is null but maybe you want to assign something to it. Secondly, the 5 in `if (userArray[5] == "STUDENT")` looks really strange. Why do you want to check the _same_ value `userArray.Length` times? (hint, `i` is never even used)

Comment: Additionally if since userArray is string[][], userArray[5] would return datatype string[] which should not be comparable to string "STUDENT".

Comment: BTW every array is a pointer. In .NET they're just called "reference types".

Comment: Is StudentArray not a string[][]? I thought this was an array type?
 5 is the position in the array that I am checking.
 if I want to assign something to 'StudentArray[j]' What should I assign as I am waiting for the check on the '"STUDENT"'
    I see what you mean about the 'i' that was meant to be with the userArray

Comment: In .NET variables are type-safe. Which means unlike in for example JavaScript you cannot wildly assign variables to each other. You declare string[][] userArray which means that userArray is an array of arrays of string. An access to the first index returns an array of string. And yet you try to compare this string[] to a string "STUDENT".

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: The problem with your code is (and what we cannot see from your snippet) is that every first-level index entry may be null. And so can every second-level entry. Take this small example: 
userArray = new string[2][]; userArray[0] = new string[2]; userArray[0][1] = "test";
In this small example both userArray[1] as well as userArray[0][0] are still null, because they were not initialized!
For your code that means that userArray[i] could be null and that means an attempt to access userArray[i][5] would result in the NullReferenceException.

Comment: I have just print the value that the FOR statement is trying to use and there are definitely values stored in userArray

Comment: The contents of userArray lookssomething like this: (1, password, Staff, Staff, 0, STAFF)

Comment: ok in what line exactly do you get your null pointer?

Comment: The eror is in this line               'StudentArray[j][x] = userArray[i][x];'

Comment: When debugging, open the watch window (menu Debug -> Windows). Now break at this line in every iteration and put the following variables in the watch window: StudentArray, StudentArray[j], userArray and userArray[i]. This will point you to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Galandil's code. One important thing is to never try to do too many things at once. It makes it way harder to debug

```cs
public string[][] userArray;
public string[][] StudentArray;

public void UserSorting(string[][] userArray)
{
    List<string[]> studentList = new List<string[]>();

    //for each row in user array
    for (int userIndex = 0; userIndex < userArray.Length; userIndex++)
    {
        //Compares the stored account type to STUDENT
        if (userArray[userIndex] != null && userArray[userIndex].Length > 5 && userArray[userIndex][5] == "STUDENT")
        {
            string[] userAttributes = userArray[userIndex];

            //for each user value copy into the new array
            string[] studentAttributes = new string[userAttributes.Length];

            for (int attributeIndex = 0; attributeIndex < userAttributes.Length; attributeIndex++)
            {
                studentAttributes[attributeIndex] = userAttributes[attributeIndex];
                Debug.Log(studentAttributes[attributeIndex]);
            }

            studentList.Add(studentAttributes);
        }
    }
    StudentArray = studentList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're several mistakes in your code.

First of all, when looping an `array` (or anything that implements `IEnumerable`), the condition must be `index < array.Length` and not `<=`, if the `Length` is 6, the indexes will go from 0 to 5, trying to access index 6 will throw an out of bound exception.

Second, you should always check if `userArray[i] != null` before checking for its content: if may well be that one index of `userArray` has not been declared, and that would throw an exception.

Third, you have to be sure that `StudentArray` has been declared, with the same number of elements as `userArray`, since you can't modify the length of arrays like you do with `Lists`.

Finally, for all the previous reasons, you should start to use `List`s instead of `arrays`, they're a lot more easier to modify and mantain.

Anyway, to fix all the mistakes I listed, the code should look like this:

```cs
public string[][] userArray;
public string[][] StudentArray;
public int j;

private void Start() {
    //First index length just an example
    userArray = new string[3][];
    StudentArray = new string[userArray.Length][];
    //These 2 declarations are just to let you see that the code can skip undeclared arrays
    userArray[0] = new string[6];
    userArray[0][5] = "STUDENT";
    userArray[2] = new string[8];
    UserSorting(userArray);
}

public string[][] UserSorting(string[][] userArray) {
    j = 0;
    //for each row in user array
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.Length; i++) {
        //Compares the stored account type to STUDENT
        if (userArray[i] != null) {
            if (userArray[i][5] == "STUDENT") {
                //for each user value copy into the new array
                StudentArray[j] = new string[userArray[i].Length];
                for (int x = 0; x < userArray[i].Length; x++) {
                    StudentArray[j][x] = userArray[i][x];
                    Debug.Log(StudentArray[j][x]);
                }
                //moves onto the next line ready for the next iteration 
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return StudentArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, StudentArray is declared the same length as the userArray, does this matter? as not all values in userArray are going to be students

Comment: That's the problem with `arrays`. If you want to have a `StudentArray` with a length exactly as the STUDENT entries in `userArray`, you should first check how many STUDENT entries are in `userArray`, then declare `StudentArray = new string[entriesFound][];`, and finally start to populate the array.
I strongly suggest you start to use `Lists` instead of `arrays`.

Comment: If the answer is satisfying, pls don't forget to tag it as accepted by clicking on the gray checkmark you can find on the left of the answer itself.

Comment: So is it not worth iterating through the entirety of the userArray and finding the number of student accounts first? and then moving them across? or not?

Comment: @OscarDawe It's like you have a book with all the people in your school. And now you have an equally large but empty book into which you want to write only the students. In the first book there is a teacher on page 3. What do you do in the second book with page 3? Leave it empty? If so you will have to be prepared later to encounter empty pages.

Comment: Okay I get that part, but how does the code you've given negotiate around this issue? does it just leave all blank rows at the end of the array?

Comment: It doesn't. That's why everyone is advising you to use lists. I will build up on @Galandil's code to show you an example.

Comment: Correction: @Galandil's code already reduces the target array. That's why s/he counts the `j` variable individually.

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena no, the code in my answer doesn't reduce the target array, the length is still the same as the source array, it just writes the results leaving the blank elements at the end.

Comment: @Galandil Sorry, you are right of course. I just saw the independent `j` variable only counting up upon success and made the wrong conclusion.